# Query to find the min and max value of a specific column in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have some collection in MongoDB, e.g. like the below one

```
[
  { "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") },
  { "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") },
  { "_id" : 3, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 5, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:05:00Z") },
  { "_id" : 4, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z") },
  { "_id" : 5, "item" : "xyz", "price" : 5, "quantity" : 10, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-15T09:05:00Z") }
]
```

I want to find the minimum and maximum value of "_id" or anyother field. I am using "MongoDB Compass". How can i write a query in MongoDB Compass which gives me the minimum and maximum value of a particular column

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it in the `filter` textbox, i.e. by query and NOT by aggregation (as sushant suggested), then you can sort your target field in descending order and set the limit to 1.

**Example: Min Price**
[image]

---

**Example: Max Price**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$group` pipeline using $min and $max operators in aggregate pipeline as

```
 collectionName.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:null,minVal: {$min: "$price"},maxVal: {$max: "$price"},}}
   ])
```

Comment: No, its not working in Compass. Basically i want to write query on the "filter" textbox of mongoDB compass @sushant mehta

Comment: I've not used compass, but can't we use aggregate builder in compass.https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/aggregation-pipeline-builder/

Comment: I don't know, i am a new to MongoDB and Compass @sushant mehta

Comment: if you can only use query then you can use sort with limit 1 on the key whose min and max value you want to get

Comment: You can check the link to see how to use aggregate in compass and just add above group in pipeline